# Why exist difference in DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations output and supported timezones list?

Tags: php, timezone

For example [here](http://php.net/manual/ru/timezones.asia.php) we see Asia/Novosibirsk, but this timezone absent in DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations output. So when i run symfony_requirements i get error about timezone. Why DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations don't have some timezones?

Comment: Is your timezone database up to date?

Comment: You mean  /usr/share/zoneinfo/ ? In this dir Novosibirsk exists in Asia directory. And now i realized that i don't know where from listAbbreviations takes timezones list.

Comment: I found that DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations use hardcoded list of timezones from here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/lib/timezonemap.h . So no any timezone database used. And i don't understand why here http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php listed timezones that absent in timezonemap.h

Comment: Update your PHP timezone database (and/or PHP itself) and try again?

Comment: According my this https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2601 pull request i should make request in this file: https://github.com/derickr/timelib/blob/master/timezonemap.h and as i see this file don't have required timezones, so updating php can't help me.

Comment: Try posting a bug report in that repository. Derick will probably see it quickly! He cares